# javascript stop audio from button click

Tags: javascript, audio, mp3

When the function generate is called, the sound should be played. If button is triggered sound sound should be stopped. What's the best way to do this?

```
    <script>

    var audio = new Audio('assets/spin.mp3');

        function generate()
            {

                /* some code goes here*/
                audio.play();
            }

    </script>

    <button onClick="game.rotationAngle=0; game.draw();generate();audio.stop();">start</button>
```

It's a kind of reset I need to perform when the button is triggered. That's why the sound needs to be stopped, before it will run again.

I get this error in debug:
[image: error]

Comment: You mean, you do want to trigger between the start / stop by clicking on the same button? Create a variable (flag) and change it's value on click.

Comment: When I hit the button I get this error in my debuger:http://i.stack.imgur.com/95sEn.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should differentiate between clicking *nth* and *(n+1)th* time. To do this, just check if the audio is paused or not.
2. Using `audio` isn't valid outside the `<script>` tag, since you define it in the script tags.
3. You should also set the current time to zero if you want to start the track over.

Below is the resulting code.

```
<script>
    var audio = new Audio('assets/spin.mp3');
    function generate() {
        /* some code goes here*/
        if(audio.paused) {audio.currentTime=0;audio.play()}
                   else  audio.pause();
    }
</script>
<button onClick="game.rotationAngle=0; game.draw();generate();">start</button>
```

Comment: The script I use is for some kind of 'wheel of fortune'. For this I need the sound to be played from beginning each time the button is hit. You know what I mean?

Comment: This works fine, but it shows me this error in debugger, when hitting the button more than once. http://puu.sh/pp6fV/972009d73e.png

Comment: @peke But it does work? As for the error, [it looks like it's a bug in the engine itself.](https://github.com/google/blockly/issues/299)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use `audio.pause()` instead since there is no `stop` method. If you check `Audio.prototype.stop` it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function as `audio.stop()`.
You can use the following instead:

```
function generate() {
    if(!audio.paused) { /* Check if it's not paused */
        audio.pause();  /* To pause the audio */
        audio.currentTime = 0;  /* To reset the time back to 0 */
    }
    else {
        audio.play();  /* To make it play again */
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `audio.pause()` instead of `audio.stop()`